# JavaScript datepicker calendar popup window stays around for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

We're using Javascript [datepicker widget](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).

As suggested, we simply do

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

In the datepicker we use, after you select a date in the calendar popup window,
the calendar popup window does not close, unlike [some other datepicker I've seen](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

How is behaviour specified?

The behaviour we have is not necessarily wrong, because when you select a date, you can change your mind and want to select another date.  So it's helpful if the calendar window
doesn't close in this case.

However, you have to click on the background for this calendar popup window to close.

On this page, we also have a submit button (to submit the newly created object).
If you don't click on the background before clicking on the submit button,
we notice (in IE8) that this calendar popup window sometimes (not always)
sticks around even on the next page and cannot be closed.  It's quite annoying.

Has anyone seen this problem?  What's the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried closing the datepicker after it throws the `changeDate` event?

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
  .on('changeDate', function(ev){
    //Do something with the date.
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('hide');
});
```